# why is there a 5-10 second delay during meteor Tracker.autorun before database changes are updated in UI?

Tags: meteor, d3.js

I'm updating a d3.js chart in my meteor UI in response to MongoDB updates.
For some reason it takes anywhere between 5 to 10 seconds before the changes, which I make to my local MongoDB manually, are reflected in the chart.

Here is the code, perhaps someone would spot the reason for this delay:

```
    Template.diagram.rendered = function(){

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
          width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
          height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
      x = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split(''))
        .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

      y = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0,0.15])
        .range([height, 0]);
      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom");
      var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(y)
      .orient("left")
      .ticks(10, "%");

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," +
            margin.top + ")");
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);
      svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis)
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", ".71em")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Frequency");

      this.autorun(function(){
          var data = Letters.find().fetch();
        if (!data.length){
            return;
        }
        var bars = svg
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data, function(d){return d._id;});
        bars.enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
          .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
          .attr("height",0)
          .attr("y", height)
          .transition()
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height -
          y(d.frequency); });
        bars
          .transition()
          .duration(200)
          .ease("sin-out")
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.frequency); })
          .attr("height", function(d) { return height -
          y(d.frequency); });
      });
    };
```

Comment: Is this the default dB created by meteor or something else? Just from the title it sounds like you don't have oplog tailing on.

Comment: Yes - this is one of the default database created by meteor. How do I check if oplog tailing is on?

Answer (score 0):

Once I have this question posted on meteor forums, I was pointed to a meteor blog post from 2014, which describes the oplog tailing feature, and the fact, that it is only on by default in the dev instance. This made me realize, that, by using MONGO_URL env variable with my dev application, I was forcing my meteor app to work with the MongoDB instance, which was running on my mac all the time, independently from my meteor development, and, as such, was considered as "production" by my meteor app. Once I have switched the app to work with ad-hock mongo connection / db, the oplog tailing went into effect, and I started to see immediate event propagation to the browser. Thanks, @dburles from the meteor forums!